# How to move value (like a string sentence) from one page to another in JavaScript, the pages are going to be stored locally

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm trying to move a sentence from one HTML page to another using JavaScript, I saw an article about using the `console.log("sentence")` to log the value into the console and then reading from the console in the other page, but I don't know how to read the value in another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the localStorage (or better sessionStorage) of the browser.

The following snippet accesses the current domain's local Storage object and adds a data item to it using Storage.setItem().

```
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
```

The syntax for reading the localStorage item is as follows:

```
var cat = localStorage.getItem('myCat');
```

The syntax for removing the localStorage item is as follows:

```
localStorage.removeItem('myCat');
```

The syntax for removing all the localStorage items is as follows:

```
// Clear all items
localStorage.clear();
```

[localStorage docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)